# How can I rewrite this such that it doesn't need a return statement out side the foreach

Tags: laravel, phpunit

So for testing purposes this method, which uses **laravel** relations will never reach the return statement out side the foreach loop. How do I know? Because the fieldName exists on one of these form fields, I just don't know which one, hence the for loop.

Consider the following method:

```
protected function fetchFieldLabel(string $fieldName) {
    foreach ($this->forms as $form) {
        $foundField = $form->fields->where('name', '=', $fieldName)->first();

        if (!is_null($foundField)) {
            return $foundField->label;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I should not need the `return null` at the end of the method, if I remove it, my code coverage is not 100% on this method, so I am looking for a better way to return the `$foundField->label` with out a for loop as the code coverage will always hit this return statement (eventually) and it will never leave the foreach loop.

For context:

[image]

I have been looking at [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-filter) but I am unsure how to use it in this context.

When I write something like:

```
    $this->forms->filter(function($form) use($fieldName) {
        return $form->fields->where('name', $fieldName);
    })->first();
```

I get the whole form object, all its fields and all their dependencies.

For reference:

- Form has many fields, field belongs to form.

**Any thoughts on how I could write this such that I get 100% code coverage and not have a "never reached `return null`"**

*PS: All I want is to find the field (in the collection of forms) which `$fieldName` belongs to and return the label of that field.*

*PS2: There is no test I could write where it would return the null, because the field name in this case will **ALWAYS** exist on the collection of forms fields. Again, we just don't know which one it exists on.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way would be using a `break` instead of the return.

```php
protected function fetchFieldLabel(string $fieldName) {
    $label = null;

    foreach ($this->forms as $form) {
        $foundField = $form->fields->where('name', '=', $fieldName)->first();

        if (! is_null($foundField)) {
            $label = $foundField->label;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $label;
}
```

Otherwise you could use the `Collection` directly like this:

```php
protected function fetchFieldLabel(string $fieldName) {
    return optional($this->forms->map(function ($form) use ($fieldName) {
        return $form->fields->firstWhere('name', $fieldName);
    })->filter()->first())->label;
}
```

So basically, you map the form into the field that matches the `$fieldName`, which would return `null` if the form doesn't have a field. Then `filter` to remove out those that doesn't pass the truth value test. And then chaining `first` to retrieve the first field. Finally `label` to get the label of the field.

You could also wrap everything in the [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-optional) helper to make sure the `label` never throws an error if no field is found even though you said that should never happen.

Comment: Second example will probably bug because `->label` may not be defined.

Comment: @Flame I've wrapped it with the `optional` helper now, should never throw an error anymore.

Comment: @Flame Label would always exist on a field though, so could you explain how it could bug out?

Comment: `firstWhere` may return null depending on the input, so the `map()->filter()->first()` may return null as well since `map()` could be `[null, null]` and `filter()` makes it as `[]` and `first()` gets the first element which is null.

Comment: tbh this function is using quite a bit of collection functions, it might be easier to read to just `break` in your regular for-loop.

Comment: @flame I may have to do that because `optional` when used throws:  `Call to undefined function App\Health\Reports\Builder\optianl()` Break does seem cleaner though to read.

Comment: @TheWebs I made a typo in my example. It should be `optional` instead of `optianl`.

Comment: @ChinLeung If I would have read ..... LOL. It's ok, I am gonna use the break for better "remembering of what this does" and for readability. Thank you kind sir :D